# Nonhomogenous Inequality, symmetric

Tags: inequality

Show that $3Z+\left(\dfrac{3-X}{3Y-X} \right)^3+\dfrac{X(3-X)}{3Y-X} \ge 5$, where

$X=abc,$
$Y=\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3},$
$Z=\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}$,

for positive real $a$, $b$, and $c$, such that $abc \leq 1$.

I first tried to expand but it became too messy, so I instead collapsed the terms into X, Y, and Z. However, even with the nice symmetric forms of X, Y, and Z, when we use the UVW method, it still will be really messy, and it is really hard to fit the condition $abc \leq 1$ in.

Comment: I think it would look prettier if you deleted the factor of $1/3$ from $Y$ and from $Z$, since we are just multiplying them by $3$ anyway.

Comment: I tried to do this so that it is easy to check x=y=z=1

Comment: try the uvw method

Comment: It's not homogenous... would probably be too messy if I did it.

Comment: any ideas???????

Comment: The current prevailing mood on MSE is to close questions in which no work has been indicated. By now you must be aware of that.

Comment: Edited to show that

Comment: I have expanded the inequality expressions and only few summands have collapsed. The final form consists of twenty four homogeneous symmetric polynomials with total degrees from zero to twelve, so it shouldn’t be simplifiable.